# Error in accessing the cobalt API using Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to use the [Cobalt API](https://github.com/wukko/cobalt/blob/current/docs/API.md)—not the one you may know—to download videos, and for starters, I wrote a Python script that would download an YouTube video, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ. However, I can't seem to get it. I provided the URL to the API using POST as `application/json` (as is there in the documentation), but it still didn't work.

I wrote a Python script that looks something like this:

```py
import requests
import urllib.parse
import json

url = 'https://co.wuk.sh/api/json'
youtube_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
encoded_url = urllib.parse.quote(youtube_url)

data = json.dumps({'url': encoded_url})

response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

I ran this and then at the Python shell, I did:

```py
>>>response.text
'{"status":"error","text":"i can\'t guess what you want to download! please give me a link :("}'
```

The response returned an error saying that I hadn't provided a link, when I clearly had. What's the problem here? What did I do wrong?

Comment: There are a few keys that you need.  Specifically, the ```url```, ```vCodec``` (since you're downloading from yt.  That's the extent of my understanding.

Comment: Nope, I added `vCodec` but that isn't working either. Moreover, a default value of `h264` is already supplied for `vCodec`, so that shouldn't be the reason for the problem, I guess.